# Java:Trying to read the numbers out of a string in a loop, fails when I attempt to change the array number

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

Basically my loops works fine as this:

```
 for(y=0; y<10; y++){ 
         for(x=0; x<10; x++){
            tileNum = row[column].charAt(x) - '0';
            tiles[tileNum].draw(x*tileSize,y*tileSize);
         }
     }
```

but fails to compile when I add this line:

```
 for(y=0; y<10; y++){ 
         column++;
         for(x=0; x<10; x++){
            tileNum = row[column].charAt(x) - '0';
            tiles[tileNum].draw(x*tileSize,y*tileSize);
         }
     }
```

I have no clue why, but I figure there's something about string arrays or loops I'm not realizing. Any way around this?

What I'm trying to do is render a grid of tiles.
Each row of tiles is stored in an array of 10 numbers that are read and then rendered as a tile. The x for loop renders the row, and the y for loop repeats the row below it, and so on.

What it does in the first scenario is simply render the first row 10 times downwards. but I want it to render different rows, so after it renders a row, I'd like it to move on to the next row, or next String array in "row". however, any attempt to alter the number "column" resultants in not compiling.

Apparently moving the column++; outside the loop causes everything to render and then crash. It something about  tileNum = row[column].charAt(x) - '0'; I guess

Comment: well, in your 2nd loop, you have a `column++`, and we have no idea what difference is it making.

Comment: try moving `column++` below the `for x` loop

Comment: What do you mean by fail?  Fails to compile, gives unexpected results, ... ?

Comment: basically if I try to change the variable on the "row" array within the loop it crashes. It doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Make sure `row` has 10 elements to begin with. @user2753909

Comment: how would I go about testing if it is an ArrayOutOfBounds?

Comment: @user2753909: How do you know it 'crashes'? What indicates this?

Comment: row indeed has 10 elements, and if I change the words column to any number (0-9) it works and renders the specific row

Comment: it simply doesn't compile, the console gives no hints.

Comment: @user2753909: you are saying that the 1st variant Compiles fine while the second variant doesn't 'Compile'? Please note 'doesn't compile' is very different from 'crashes'.

Comment: @ boxed__l Correct. The first variant compiles (though with not the correct results) and the second does not. I also am pretty sure I've ruled out an ArrayOutOfBounds.

If you'd like to know exactly what I'm doing (may be fairly lengthy to explain) I can if you think it'd be helpful.

Comment: Change your discussion to chat. Its gonna go long.

Comment: edited the post with an explanation. hopefully someone can help =/

Answer (score 0):

```
try it once '

   for(y=0; y<10; y++){

      for(x=0; x<10; x++){

        tileNum = row[column].charAt(x) - '0';
        tiles[tileNum].draw(x*tileSize,y*tileSize);
     }

     column++;

  }'
```